# Observable doesn't end when event is emitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to use an Observable and EventEmitter to a run a method a every 15 seconds and terminate it if a particular event if fired by the EventEmitter.

// events.js

```
'use strict'

const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const emitter = new EventEmitter()

module.exports = emitter
```

// magic.js

```
'use strict'

const eventbus = require('../config/events')
const Observable = require('rx').Observable

const actionEvent$ = Observable.fromEvent(eventbus, 'action')

const run = (matches) => {
    // create observable from timer
    const timer$ = Observable.timer(0, 15000)
    // create observable from matches array
    const matches$ = Observable.from(matches)

    Observable
        .zip(timer$, matches$, (timer, match) => {
            return match
        })
        .takeUntil(actionEvent$)
        .subscribe((match) => {
            // do something
        },
        (err) => {
            // handle error
        },
        () => {
            // do cleanup
        })
}
}

module.exports = {
    run
}
```

// controller.js

```
'use strict'

const magic = require('../utils/magic')
const eventbus = require('../config/events')

module.exports = {
   handle: (req, res, done) => {
      magic.run([{},{}, {}, ...])

      setTimeout(() => { eventbus.emit('action', true) }, 20000)
      return done()
   }
}
```

Calling `handle` method on the controller via route, triggers the observable sequence but the sequence doesn't end when the `action` event is emitted from the `eventbus`.

Comment: Do you know if the same Observable emits values or if a new Observable is emitted? I am not sure if the `setTimeout` doesn't start a new Observable chain that has no relevance for the `.takeUntil`.

Comment: I am also not fully understanding why you are using `.zip` here. Are you just trying to emit values either every 15 seconds or whenever a new match exists?

Comment: I want to emit values every 15 seconds, and cancel when the event triggered with `.takeUntil`

Comment: What happens if no action has happened in the last 15 seconds, what do you want to emit then?

Comment: If no action happens it should continue emitting the values it has

Comment: It would be good if you could create a marble chart. And I misspoke, I wanted to know what happens if no match exists. What is match anyways, is this an array? Is it an `Observable` itself? I understand you want to emit some value(s) every 15 seconds until someone cancels it by triggering the `eventbus` event. I am still not sure why you use `.zip` and I am not sure what kind of matches you want to emit throughout.

Comment: `match` is an object emitted from the `zipped` observables. I'm using `.zip` to combine timer observable and the observable from an array, this allows the zipped Observable to emit an object every 15 seconds

Comment: When I tried to test your code, it worked for me. I used `const actionEvent$ = Observable.of('disturbance').delay(9000);` as the stopping `Observable` and it worked. Not sure why yours doesn't work. Maybe try if the event is really emitted `.do(console.log)`. Btw, I like the way you are using `zip`, pretty clever.

Comment: @Spurious Figured it out, my events weren't firing properly, switch to using a redis pubsub and the node eventemitter. Thanks for the help though